# HttpWebRequest in parallel

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, task-parallel-library

I need to send 40 request to a REST service, and was thinking that I might try to make it parallel to save some time, since each http request takes close to one second.

I've pasted a section of my code (simplified for illustration) below to show my approach. When I execute it in parallel about 8 out of the 40 messages return a status code 500 - 'Internal server Error'. If I execute it in a 'normal' foreach loop all is good.

My question is, am I parallelising/doing this the wrong way, or might it be the code in the other end?

```cs
 Parallel.ForEach(Messages, message=>  
        try
        {
            //Create a HttpWebRequest, ie. request.GetRequestStream()
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = request.GetWebRequest(uri, RequestType.PUT,message);

            using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                //You should make sure you read the response stream, even if you don't care about the response. 
                //This should help not producing too many lingering connections.
                new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

                if (webResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    lock (lockObject)
                    {
                        //Collect errors in a list
                        responses.Add("Something went wrong" + webResponse.StatusCode);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException web)
        {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)web.Response;
            lock (lockObject)
            {
               //Collect errors in a list
               responses.Add("Something went wrong" + webResponse.StatusCode); }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                //Collect errors in a list
                responses.Addstring.Format("Unspecified Error:{0}", e)}); }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Maybe you can use an HTTP sniffer like fidller to see if there is more information in the header or body of the status 500 responses?

Comment: It looks fine to me. I suspect the service at the other end may be enforcing some kind of request limit to prevent DoS attacks. You could try using Wireshark or something to make sure your raw HTTP requests look as they should.

Comment: @Elad Lachmi: I've done that, there is nothing of use in the content or header

Comment: If you're getting “Internal Server Error”, then that means there is some error on the server. Either this is deliberate or some bug in their code. I think you will need to contact the owners of that server.

Comment: I see you're doing PUT operations. Is it possible that some of your messages are putting duplicate data, and if two messages try to put the same data concurrently, the Web server will encounter an error? (For example, two threads trying to upload the same file at the same time.)

Comment: According to fiddler, and previous debugging sessions, theres no dublicate data. I'll contact the service provider, thanks for all of your responses...